# Laravel 5.2 Cannot get auth middleware to work in resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This is how the `HolidaysController` looks like at the moment:

```
public function _construct(){

    $this->middleware('auth');
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the holidays.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // get all the holiday requests from the database
    $holidayReq = HolidayRequest::all();

    // load the view and pass the holiday requests
    return view('holidays.index')->with('holidayRequests',$holidayReq);
}
```

The `auth` middleware is the boilerplate Laravel middleware, I haven't changed it. 
Once I logout and then try to access the `/holidays` route, which leads to the `index()` method above, I get the following ErrorException, instead of it going to the login page as it should:

`Trying to get property of non-object (View: *followed by long address of the blade file`

I've refreshed Apache several times, but it still doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: Add the stack trace to the information provided above. It's pretty important in terms of debugging your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method you defined as your constructor is not a constructor in PHP.

`_construct != __construct`